# Update two or more table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have three tables.
1st table is tbl_user

```
id  u_name  p_list
1   demo1   1,3,
2   demo2   4,3,1,
3   demo3   2,3,
4   demo4   2,5,
```

Second table is tbl_product

```
id  product_name
1   example1
2   example2
3   example3
4   example4
5   example5
```

third table is tbl_order_list that show the list of order to the users. tbl look like

```
id  pid  uid
1   1    1,2,
2   4    2,
3   3    1,2,3,
4   5    4,
```

now i want 
if i'll update tbl user means if i'll remove pid of column p_list of tbl_user than tbl_user will be updated and also tbl_order_list is update

"Example"  if i'll remove 3 in p_list of id 2 from tbl_user than table is look like

```
id  u_name  p_list
1   demo1   1,3,
2   demo2   4,1,  //(pid =3 is remove of demo2)
3   demo3   2,3,
4   demo4   2,5,
```

And tbl_order_list is look like

```
id  pid  uid
1   1    1,2,
2   4    2,
3   3    1,3, //(uid =2 is remove)
4   5    4,
```

what is the solution of this problem. i want also if i'll add again pid = 3 in p_list of id = 2 of table user than table look like previous tables.

**QUERY** (From Comments)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_user SET u_name='$userName',slug='$userSlug',password='$userPassword',email='$use‌​rEmail',role='$userRole',p_list='$userList',status='$userStatus',modified_‌​date='$userDate' WHERE id='$uId'");
```

Help Me

Comment: Please POST Your Tried Query. We Are Not Going To Write Query From SCRATCH.

Comment: `mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_user` SET u_name`='$userName',`slug`='$userSlug',`password`='$userPassword',`email`='$userEmail',`role`='$userRole',`p_list`='$userList',`status`='$userStatus',`modified_date`='$userDate' WHERE `id`='$uId'");`

Comment: You really should take a look at your table design... It looks like you should normalize it. Read more about it here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I do absolutely agree ;o)

Answer (score 0):

So far, I'm not seeing any real correlation to php, but whatever.

I would highly *suggest* using a normal form (see database normalization) and deduplicate your data. tbl_order_list is a very bad table, as is tbl_user. tbl_order_list shouldn't have an id field, the uid field should contain exactly one uid and the primary key should be (pid,uid) (so both fields). By that point it should be called tbl_order. If you want a list of all pids for a uid or all uids for a pid - at some point - you can query like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uid) 
FROM tbl_order 
WHERE pid=[your pid of interest]
GROUP BY pid
```

and vice-versa (replace uid with pid and pid with uid). If you want to query it at the same time with the rest of your userdata:

```
SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(o.pid)
FROM tbl_user u
LEFT JOIN tbl_order o ON (u.id=o.uid)
[WHERE u.id=[your uid of interest]]
GROUP BY u.id
```

(and similarly with the tbl_product).

When using mysql >= 5.7 you can create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_order_list AS SELECT pid, GROUP_CONCAT(uid) FROM tbl_order GROUP BY pid.
```

Adding or Removing an order then would result in deleting/inserting a row in tbl_order.

**Summary**: Make a table `tbl_order` (uid,pid) that contains the links between uids and pids (one link per row). Join this table in, when you need the the links. *Please* don't save "references" as a comma-separated list in a string field unless there is a very very very good reason.

If you infact have a very very good reason, consider adding comma (`,`) to the beginning and end of your lists, meaning. So:

```
id  pid  uid
1   1    ,1,2,
2   4    ,2,
3   3    ,1,2,3,
4   5    ,4,
```

This way you can safely search, add, remove entries:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_order_list WHERE uid LIKE '%,[uid of interest],%'
UPDATE tbl_order_list SET uid=CONCAT(uid,',',[uid to add]) WHERE id=[order to update]
UPDATE tbl_order_list SET uid=REPLACE(",[uid to remove],",",",uid) WHERE id=[order to update]
```

(and similar for your tbl_user, if you're querying by pid in the tbl_order list, drop the id field.)

If you don't prepend a comma, you might at some point have some problems with consistency.

Anyway, I cannot stress this enough: **normalize your database structure unless you have very good reasons not to** (and be absolutely sure, they really are good reasons, because usually they aren't)